# How to align image top left in titlepage?

Tags: graphics, titles

```
\begin{titlepage}
\begin{center}

\begin{flushleft}
\begin{minipage}{1.3\linewidth}
%\begin{flushleft} %%doesn't show any change, image still aligned to center of titlepage
{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{18.png}}
%\includegraphics[scale=0.4]{18.png}}
%\end{flushleft}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\end{flushleft}


\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1}\ {\large\textmd{Department of Environment}} \\


\vspace{2cm} {\LARGE\textbf{Master Thesis}}\\ 

\vspace{0.3cm} 
{\large\textbf{in order to obtain the Degree of}\\%des akademischen Grades \\ 
\vspace{0.8cm}}

{\large{Master of Science (M.Sc.):}}\\


\vspace{0.8cm}\LARGE\textbf{Thesis Topic}\\

\end{center}

%\vspace{7 cm}
\end{titlepage}`
```

[image]

Currently I'm using this code, but doesn't give the desired output. I want the image to be left justified. like this

[image]

I'm a complete newbie here, need help!

Comment: This green line should start right at the left paper edge? Or left, as usuall text will start left, i.e. with a margin.

Comment: Where are the official guidelines for title pages of FH Jena?

Comment: The green line should start at the left of the paper edge!

Comment: How do I add an image here in comments.. I only have a sample titlepage from FH Jena..

Comment: Comments are for asking for clarifications, the extra details should go to the question. The edit button is to the left of your name.

Comment: @Johannes_B i have edited the question, Thanks!

Comment: That seems to be the right edge of the page ;-) Where to get the pictures. Is there an official download-place. Or is it campus-only?

Comment: It is campus only. A similar example would help. Neither am I able to align the minipage to the right! :(

Answer (score 1):

Closest i can come up with just looking at the picture.

> [image: fhjena]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{top=0cm,a4paper,left=3cm,right=2cm,bottom=1.5cm}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{scrextend}
\usepackage{tgadventor}
\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
    \sffamily
    \vspace*{.5cm}
    \begin{addmargin}[0cm]{-2cm}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=3cm]{example-image-16x9}\par
    \end{addmargin}
        \vspace{2cm}
        {
    \centering
    {Fachbereich Elektrotechnik\par}
    \vspace{3cm}
    {\bfseries\huge Bachelorarbeit\par}
    \bigbreak
    {\bfseries zur Erlangung eines Grades\par}
    \bigbreak
    {Bachelor of Engineering\par}
    \bigbreak
    {\bfseries\LARGE I've been watchin birds more than
    insects recently, and the thing I've found with pigeons
is: they've got wings but they walk a lot\par}
}
    \vfill
    \begin{tabular}{l@{\hspace{2cm}}l}
        eingereicht von & Walzing Womnbat \\
        geboren am & 02.07.1990 \\
        Hochschulbetreur & Prof.\,Dr. Lazy Leguan \\
    \end{tabular}
    \vfill
    \begin{addmargin}[0cm]{-2cm}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=3cm]{example-image-16x9}\par
    \end{addmargin}
\end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```

Added to the list of [titlepages](https://github.com/johannesbottcher/titlepageExamples).

Comment: More specs would be nice. That way your fellow students wouldn't need to further customize.